# MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Visual Studio C#

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview, syntax-error, visual-studio-2019

I am really new to coding and I need to resolve an update problem in my project.
I wanted to update data (connected to the database) within datagridview, but it doesn't work and I do get the information about the problem below, but I can't resolve it.
I would really appreciate it if someone has an idea t resolve the issue. Thanks a lot.

---

> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: "You have an error in your SQL
> syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
> for the right syntax to use near 'Abflug=4, Abflugort='2021-11-23
> 00:00:00', Ankunft='Aachen-Merzbrück Airport', ' at line 1"

Here is my code:

```cs
private void btn_Buchungsuebersicht_update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int item = 0; item <= dataGridView_Buchungen.Rows.Count - 1; item++)
    {     
        MySqlCommand cmd2 = new MySqlCommand("Update ReserBu set IDKunde=@IDKunde; Abflug=@Abflug, Abflugort=@Abflugort, Ankunft=@Ankunft, Zielort=@Zielort, PAX=@PAX, Catering=@Catering, Flugzeitgesamt=@Flugzeitgesamt, Strecke=@Strecke, Gesamtkosten=@Gesamtkosten, BuFreigegeben=@BuFreigegeben, BuStorno=@BuStorno, Stornierungsgrund=@Stornierungsgrund where IDReserBu=@IDReserBu", conn);
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IDKunde", dataGridView_Buchungen.Rows[item].Cells[0].Value);
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Abflug", dataGridView_Buchungen.Rows[item].Cells[1].Value);
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Abflugort", dataGridView_Buchungen.Rows[item].Cells[2].Value);
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ankunft", dataGridView_Buchungen.Rows[item].Cells[3].Value);
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Zielort", dataGridView_Buchungen.Rows[item].Cells[4].Value);
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PAX", dataGridView_Buchungen.Rows[item].Cells[5].Value);
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Catering", dataGridView_Buchungen.Rows[item].Cells[6].Value);
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Flugzeitgesamt", dataGridView_Buchungen.Rows[item].Cells[7].Value);
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Strecke", dataGridView_Buchungen.Rows[item].Cells[8].Value);
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gesamtkosten", dataGridView_Buchungen.Rows[item].Cells[9].Value);
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BuFreigegeben", dataGridView_Buchungen.Rows[item].Cells[10].Value);
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BuStorno", dataGridView_Buchungen.Rows[item].Cells[11].Value);
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Stornierungsgrund", dataGridView_Buchungen.Rows[item].Cells[12].Value);

        conn.Open();
        cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
    }
    MessageBox.Show("Aenderungen erfolgreich durchgefuehrt");
}
```

Comment: `;` after `IDKunde=@IDKunde` should be a `,`

Comment: Can't see a parameter added for `@IDReserBu`

Comment: If your DGV is databinded to a datatable you can make your life so much easier by using a MySqlDataAdapter with a MySqlCommandBuilder associated; you just call `adapter.Update(theDataTable)` and it does the rest

Comment: If I add the parameter @IDReserBu I get an error (maybe because of autocrement?) You suggested 'adapter.Update' - how do I do that? Thank you for your help, I really appreciate it

Comment: But your update command requires `@IDReserBu` because it uses it in the where clause. I'm not saying you should SET the value of IDReserBu colun.. I'm saying your SQL has 13 parameters in and your C# code adds 12.. Please always say exactly what error message. "I get an error" is not useful to someone remote. (By the way, if you change the code, then post an edited version into the question; it's no point editing the code, not telling us what you changed, and saying "i edited something and i got an error")

Comment: I am sorry, I will try as you suggested. I changed the ';' to ','  and also put the parameter IDReserBU (this time I didn't receive an error), but the changes I made in the DataGrdView weren't written in the database.   changes: 'cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IDRerserBu", dataGridView_Buchungen.Rows[item].Cells[0].Value);'

Comment: But Cells[0] is IDKunde, not IDReserBu, according to the code you already put for @IDkunde parameter. Unless IDkunde and IDreserbu are the same, then you end up updating the wrong record

Comment: This is why we don't pull values out of a datagrid view and feed them back into a query. Maybe you have some datatable that downloads all 13 columns, but you only show 12 in the grid, you don't show IDReserBu.. So the grid doesn't know IDreserbu, only the table does.. and thats why we work on the datatable, not the grid view. The grid's only job is to edit those fewer columns in the table that it can see. The table is what we use to save data to the db, because its data is complete

Comment: @Jana, Caius Jard’s suggestion is very effective, maybe you can give the answer yourself and accept it as answer to change its status to Answered. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)

Comment: Thank you Caius Jard. Now I do understand much better what I have to keep in mind and how it works.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder Jingmiao Xu-MSFT I will cloe the topic